# Python convert txt file to JSON stripping and element ordering

Tags: python, json

I have a txt file that contains data split by spaces such as:

```
2017-05-16 00:44:36.151724381 +43.8187 -104.7669 -004.4 00.6 00.2 00.2 090 C
2017-05-16 00:44:36.246672534 +41.6321 -104.7834 +004.3 00.6 00.3 00.2 130 C
2017-05-16 00:44:36.356132768 +46.4559 -104.5989 -004.2 01.1 00.4 00.2 034 C
```

and I would like to convert it into JSON data to something like:

```
{"dataset": "Lightning","observation_date": "20170516004436151", "location": { "type": "point", "coordinates": [43.8187, -104.7669]}}
{"dataset": "Lightning","observation_date": "20170516004436246", "location": { "type": "point", "coordinates": [41.6321, -104.7834]}}
{"dataset": "Lightning","observation_date": "20170516004436356", "location": { "type": "point", "coordinates": [46.4559, -104.5989]}}
```

where I have to append a 'dataset':'lightning' key/val pair, combine and strip the date and time, and combine the lat/lng into a dict before doing any json conversion.

But right now I still get the date and time elements without being stripped of the "-" and ":" characters like:

```
{"observation_date": "2017-05-1600:44:36.151724381", "location": {"type": "point", "coordinates": ["+43.8187", "-104.7669"]}, "dataset": "Lightning"}
{"observation_date": "2017-05-1600:44:36.246672534", "location": {"type": "point", "coordinates": ["+41.6321", "-104.7834"]}, "dataset": "Lightning"}
{"observation_date": "2017-05-1600:44:36.356132768", "location": {"type": "point", "coordinates": ["+46.4559", "-104.5989"]}, "dataset": "Lightning"}
```

What I coded so far:

```
import json
import sys
def convert(filename):
    dataDict = {}
    txtFile = filename[0]
    print "Opening TXT file: ",txtFile
    infile = open(txtFile, "r")
    for line in infile:
        lineStrip = line.strip()
        parts = [p.strip() for p in lineStrip.split()]
        date = parts[0].strip("-") #trying to get rid of "-" but not working
        time = parts[1].strip(":") #trying to get rid of ":" and "." but not working
        dataDict.update({"dataset":"Lightning"})
        dataDict.update({"observation_date": date + time})
        dataDict.update({"location": {"type":"point", "coordinates": [parts[2], parts[3]]}})
        json_filename = txtFile.split(".")[0]+".json"
        jsonf = open(json_filename,'a')
        data = json.dumps(dataDict)
        jsonf.write(data + "\n")
        print dataDict
    infile.close()
    jsonf.close()   
if __name__=="__main__":
    convert(sys.argv[1:])
```

But I'm not sure how to strip the "-", ".", and ":" as well as place the "dataset":"lightning" element in the front.

Comment: There is a sort argument to `json.dumps()`, that sorts the keys. `x.replace('-', '')` removes a dash from a string.

Comment: Thank you Anthon! Cant believe it was this simple.

Comment: If one of the answer solves your problem, please consider *accepting* it by clicking the ✔ (checkmark) next to the answer. That is the way other people know your problem has been solved, without reading the comments. It also changes the appearance of the question and this answer in lists. If a better answer comes along, you can always change the accepted answer. You can also upvote all answers you deem valuable, but you can only accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
date = parts[0].replace("-",'') #trying to get rid of "-" but not working

time = parts[1].replace(":",'') #trying to get rid of ":" and "." but not working
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

date = parts[0].replace('-', '') 
   time = parts[1].replace(':' '')

To get the `dataset` up front in JSON, the only option you have is sort the keys:

```
data = json.dumps(dataDict, sort_keys=True)
```

You should also consider doing

```
dataDict["dataset"] = "Lightning"
```

instead of the `.update`.

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries are unordered, so you can't specify the `"dataset":"lightning"` element to be first. For that I would use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) instead or sort the json as others have mentioned.

In order to format the time correctly, I'd use a `datetime` object as such:

```
import datetime

date_string = parts[0] + parts[1]
format = "%Y-%d-%m%H:%M:%S.%f"
dt = datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
new_date_string = dt.strftime("%Y%d%m%H%M%S")
```

Using a datetime object is helpful because it plays nicely with pandas and numpy if you continue to work on the data beyond spitting out the json. It also supports mathematical operations and time zone localization if you need it to.